# (Visual Basics and Excel) How to put a certain value into cell A2 if cell A1 has something in it

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am writing a code to take information from a simple 3 text box form and save it into an Excel sheet. My current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range("A1") = TextBox1.Text
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = TextBox2.Text
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = TextBox3.Text
    oBook.SaveAs("Book1.xlsx")
    oExcel.Quit
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub
```

So when my button is clicked the info in the 3 boxes is supposed to be put into the next available cell in every row.

I want column 1 to have names and so when cell A1 equals something entered from a past filling out of the from then put the value of TextBox1.text into the next cell down and if its populated to then move to A3 and so on. What is the command to check if the first cell is filled then move onto the second?

Also, how do I get it so that I don't have to SaveAs the Excel spreadsheet as a new one and instead just add to a current one.

Thank you if you can understand what I'm saying and will help me out! I'm new to coding so this was my best shot at explaining whats going on :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open an existing workbook, use `Workbooks.Open(filename)`.

To find the last used row in column A, use something like `Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(-4162).Row`.  (-4162 is the value of the `xlUp` constant in Excel.)

To save a workbook, instead of doing a `SaveAs`, use `Save`.

Putting it all together:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\myBook.xlsx")

    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row`
    oSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
    oSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, "B").Value = TextBox2.Text
    oSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, "C").Value = TextBox3.Text
    oBook.Save
    oBook.Close
    oExcel.Quit
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub
```